# Reading xml data using classic ASP

Tags: xml, asp-classic

I have written a code for reading xml data in classic asp as follows:

```
<%


 Dim objxml
    Set objxml = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
    objxml.async = False
    objxml.load ("/abc.in/xml.xml")



set ElemProperty = objxml.getElementsByTagName("Product")
set ElemEN = objxml.getElementsByTagName("Product/ProductCode")
set Elemtown = objxml.getElementsByTagName("Product/ProductName")
set Elemprovince = objxml.getElementsByTagName("Product/ProductPrice")  

Response.Write(ElemProperty)
Response.Write(ElemEN) 
Response.Write(Elemprovince)
For i=0 To (ElemProperty.length -1) 

    Response.Write " ProductCode = " 
    Response.Write(ElemEN) 
    Response.Write " ProductName = " 
    Response.Write(Elemtown) & "<br>"
    Response.Write " ProductPrice = " 
    Response.Write(Elemprovince) & "<br>"

next

Set objxml = Nothing 
%>
```

This code is not giving proper output.
Please help me out.

The xml is:

```
<Product>
   <ProductCode>abc</ProductCode>
   <ProductName>CC Skye Hinge Bracelet Cuff with Buckle in Black</ProductName>
</Product>
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample XML?

Comment: <Product>
<ProductCode>abc</ProductCode>
<ProductName>CC Skye Hinge Bracelet Cuff with Buckle in Black</ProductName>
</Product>

Comment: Added the xml to the question because comments are very poor place for it. Could do with seeing a little more of it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%   

Set objXMLDoc = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.3.0")    
objXMLDoc.async = False    
objXMLDoc.load Server.MapPath("/abc.in/xml.xml")

Dim xmlProduct       
For Each xmlProduct In objXMLDoc.documentElement.selectNodes("Product")
     Dim productCode : productCode = xmlProduct.selectSingleNode("ProductCode").text   
     Dim productName : productName = xmlProduct.selectSingleNode("ProductName").text   
     Response.Write Server.HTMLEncode(productCode) & " "
     Response.Write Server.HTMLEncode(productName) & "<br>"   
Next   

%>
```

Notes:

- Don't use Microsoft.XMLDOM use the explicit MSXML2.DOMDocument.3.0
- Use `Server.MapPath` to resolve virtual paths
- Use `selectNodes` and `selectSingleNode` instead of`getElementsByTagName`.  The `getElementsByTagName` scans all descendants so can return unexpected results and then you always need to index into the results even though you know you expect only one return value.
- Always `Server.HTMLEncode` data when sending to the response.
- Don't put ( ) in weird places, this is VBScript not JScript.

Comment: MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0 calls the most recent version

Answer (score 5):

Here an example how to read your data, given the xml is

```
<Products>
  <Product> 
    <ProductCode>abc</ProductCode> 
    <ProductName>CC Skye Hinge Bracelet Cuff with Buckle in Black</ProductName> 
  </Product>
  <Product> 
    <ProductCode>dfg</ProductCode> 
    <ProductName>another product</ProductName></Product>
</Products>
```

The following script

```
<%

Set objXMLDoc = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM") 
objXMLDoc.async = False 
objXMLDoc.load("xml.xml") 

Set Root = objXMLDoc.documentElement
Set NodeList = Root.getElementsByTagName("Product")

For i = 0 to NodeList.length -1
  Set ProductCode = objXMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("ProductCode")(i)
  Set ProductName = objXMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("ProductName")(i)
  Response.Write ProductCode.text & " " & ProductName.text & "<br>"
Next

Set objXMLDoc = Nothing

%>
```

gives

```
abc CC Skye Hinge Bracelet Cuff with Buckle in Black
dfg another product
```

Comment: This works but use of `getElementByTagName` ought to set alarm bells off because it will lead to pain in the end.

Comment: No its just a serious pain to get things correct using `getElementByTagName` in this way.  Its better to navigate the XML with `selectNodes` and `selectSingleNode`.